# Finding z-score of probability

Tags: statistics

I am learning the finance topic value at risk and trying to understand the number of standard deviations.

I dont quite get why was 1.65 used to multiply against the std dev instead of 1.644853 as shown in the calculator below (used to retrieve the z-score from the probability)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: @BruceET, can you explain furthur? I am confused with these definitions.

Comment: Original comment replaced by Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first panel you posted, $Q$ seems to be the probability *above* $z$ under a standard normal
curve. So the program gives $Q = 0.049471$ for $z = 1.65.$ That is, if
$Z \sim \mathsf{NORM}(0,1),$ then $P(Z > 1.65) = 0.049471.$ 
Then $P(Z \le 1.64) = 1 - 0.049471 = 0.950529,$ by the complement rule of
probability.

I'm not sure I understand how your program is working, so I'll give some results from R statistical software. I have used it a lot and trust its output. In R, `pnorm` gives the probability *below* the cutoff
value inside (), and `qnorm` gives the cutoff that has the probability
inside () below it. This matches the usual definition of *quantile* in statistics books.

```
pnorm(1.65)
## 0.9505285      # P(Z < 1.65)
pnorm(-1.65)
## 0.04947147     # P(Z < -1.65)
qnorm(.05)
## -1.644854      # q such that P(Z < q) = .05
qnorm(0.950529)
## 1.650005       # q such that P(Z < q) = .050529
qnorm(0.04947147)
## -1.65          # q such that P(Z < q) = .04947149
```

Because the density function of $Z$ is symmetrical, it is also true that $P(Z < -1.65) = 0.049471.$ The figure might be misleading you in two ways. First, it does not
stress that $z = -1.65,$ that $z = \mu - 1.65\sigma$ (note the $-$ sign
in the figure). Second, the tail probability is shown as $5\% = 0.05$ while
the printout (in very tiny type) shows $0.049471 \approx 0.05$ instead of
*exactly* $0.05.$

**Is it possible that your figure has a missing minus sign in the box for "Given z"?**

---

In the second panel, you enter $Q = .95$ and get the answer $z = 1.644853.$
Now $Q$ seems to be defined as the probability *below* the requested cutoff. That is, $P(Z \le 1.644853) = 0.95.$

R statistical software works the same here as it did above:

```
qnorm(.95)
## 1.644854     # c = 1.644854 is the cutoff with P(Z < c) = 0.95
pnorm(1.644854)
## 0.95         # P(Z < 1.644854) = 0.95
pnorm(1.645)
## 0.9500151    # P(Z < 1.645) = (nearly) 0.95: '1.645' is the value printed in many books
```

> Anyhow, the two results you show from your program seem inconsistent. Maybe your program changes the meaning of $Q$ depending on whether $z$ is positive or negative. Maybe your first (graph) and second (Calculate Q) images are not from the same session. Maybe there is some 'setting' for the program you don't
>   know about or did not mention. Maybe the picture you captured for the top panel has
>   a missing minus sign.